# How to determine the tab character size in spaces?

Tags: java, string

I understand that the tab character ('\t') size depends on where you output it. 
But how would you programmatically measure it? That is: how to find the number of spaces needed to print an equivalent '\t' character?

Comment: In what context? AWT? Swing? The web?

Comment: Any. I want to count when I manipulate the string.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself: "I understand that the tab character size greatly depends on where you output it" - and then you want to know the size *without saying where you're outputting it*. That's like saying, "I know the number of days in February depends on the year - but how many days does February have?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot measure it, for the size is defined in and determined by the interface you are sending the control character to

what you **can** do is to set your own tabsize and count the characters you have written in that line, to calculate how much spaces you need, so have an identation like you had with a tab

Answer (score 1):

If you go through this [link](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc3.html), it says that "The exact construction of the indentation (spaces vs. tabs) is unspecified." Mostly it is 8 spaces. But can we know the scenario for what you want the exact number.

Comment: The link is outdated

Answer (score 0):

You could display some text with spaces and some text with tab and when they line up best,  you can say they are about they same. The problem is taking a screen dump and detecting where you have displayed. this.

Instead of guessing how big a tab or space might be, you can use the layout functionality to place the text where you want. In this case, the decision is yours to make.